# Laravel Livewire how to redirect before render

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect if Auth::user()->id is not equal to Ad->user_id

it does not work inside the mount or hydrate method.

```
$this->ad = Ad::where('id', $this->ad_id);

        if ($this->ad->user_id != Auth::User()->id) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
```

Comment: "it does not work" - What, specifically, does not work? Are you getting an error? Please provide more details. Also, if `Ad` is a Model, you need to use `Ad::where('id', $this->ad_id)->first();`, or `Ad::find($this->ad_id);`; in your current code, you never execute a Query (you started one, but didn't finish it), so `$this->ad->user_id` won't work.

Comment: It does not redirect. and show exception error. Ad is a Model. I checked both Ad::where.. and Ad::find... What I really want is to redirect if Ad owerner user_id not equal to Auth::user()->id it does not work inside livewire component.

Comment: "and show exception error" - What exception? I won't ask again; please provide more details, **specifically the exception error message**.

Answer (score 0):

Livewire does not do backend redirects as far as I experienced, but rather uses JS to do them. So if you use the `$this->redirect` method, it will tell rendered component to perform the redirect. Some solutions I've seen on the web were in the render function, if you have an issue that results in a redirect being required, create an empty blade file with a simple div inside, and everywhere you need to redirect the user, set the render view as the blank one, and the FE will take the redirect. A pretty messy fix, but I did not see any better ones currently.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but below-mentioned trick worked for me.

- Rather than routing from the livewire component we can route from the livewire blade component by adding below code.

> ```
> @php
>     $carts = \Cart::getContent();
>     
>     if(count($carts) == 0)
>     {
>         $this->redirect('/shopping-cart/bag');
>     }
> @endphp
> ```

Suggestions:

- Don't use "return" while redirecting otherwise you might face some Front-end issues.
- Don't use "route" while redirecting otherwise the code won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect from `mount()` method. You can't redirect inside render as you would need to call `return redirect('/')` which would throw an error `"render" method on [App\Http\Livewire\...] must return instance of [Illuminate\View\View]`

```php
function mount(){
   if(condition fails){
      return redirect()->to('someplace');
   }
 }
```

Comment: if you have 0 pagination thhis dont work